# add Multiple steps to a Power Query conditional statement

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a single step conditional statement that works

```
    BlanksToNull = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Trimmed Text","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Trimmed Text")),
    newMergedHeader = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="newheader"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    #"Merged Columns" = 
     if newMergedHeader <> null then 
      Table.CombineColumns(BlanksToNull,mergeHeaders[List Of Headers For Concatenation], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"Merged"),
    else 
        BlanksToNull

 in  
  if newMergedHeader <> null then     
     #"Merged Columns"
  else  
     BlanksToNull
```

But if `newMergedHeader <> null` I also want to add this
 `#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})`

Is there a way to add this to the existing If statement? or do I need to write a second If statement?

I tried

```
#"Merged Columns" = 
     if newMergedHeader <> null then 
      Table.CombineColumns(BlanksToNull,mergeHeaders[List Of Headers For Concatenation], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"Merged"),
      #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})
    else 
        BlanksToNull
```

But this does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eyeballing, looks like you have an extra comma **Merged"),**

If you remove that and combine your statements I think you can do

```
#"Merged Columns" = 
 if newMergedHeader <> null then 
    Table.RenameColumns(
          Table.CombineColumns(BlanksToNull,mergeHeaders[List Of Headers For Concatenation], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"Merged")
    ,{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})
else BlanksToNull
```

but it is unclear to me why you need the whole tail end of things after the **in** instead of just replacing

```
in  
  if newMergedHeader <> null then     
    #"Merged Columns"
  else  
     BlanksToNull
```

with

```
in  #"Merged Columns"
```

since you already did all the work

Comment: Thanks that work great!.  My first Power Query if statement attempt that's why the tail end things were there. I will study your post